# Connected to the internet but unable to ping

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, ubuntu, ping

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ with a Huawei E3372 LTE USB Stick. I use a mobile simcard in this USB stick to provide it with a internet connection.

The problem now is that I can't even ping the IP assigned to this USB Stick. I'm using the "advancedinternet" APN from my ISP which should be working.

I tried the same APN in my phone and then I'm able to ping the IP address given to my phone and even host an Apache2 server on it.

Some additional information:

- The USB Stick has the network interface eth1
- My ISP is KPN
- The OS on the Pi is the latest version of Ubuntue Mate
- UFW allows all incoming connections

Comment: Dow did you find out the IP assigned to this USB Stick?

Comment: @RalfFriedl This was available in the Huawei USB Stick interface.

Comment: If you can't ping the local ip address assigned to the interface **eth1** of the LTE USB stick then you have a general local network configuration error. It has nothing to do with remote connections. What ip address is assigned to **eth1**? Look with `ip addr`. Do you can `ping 127.0.0.1`? Have you considered to use Raspbian? There is more know how about it on this site.